# How h1 tag take attributes to make it responsive - ReactJS

Tags: css, reactjs, tags, responsive

my app is ReactJS and I want to put a "h1" tag for Seo optimization. This is my code:

```
{showHeader &&
    <Col xs={12} sm={12} style={{textAlign: 'center', minWidth: '130px', paddingTop: "15px"}}>
        <div className="headerTitle">
            <p className='purple'><Translate value={TEXT} dangerousHTML/>
            </p>
        </div>
    </Col>
}
```

So , every time when I put it , it doesn't matter where.Between col, divs, p... Heading become bigger or it's not responsive. Its says that xs and ms are not allowed in h1. I try something like `<h1 xs={12}`
... I also tried with CSS, but it won't work(may be I don't know how)..I want to be responsive, 
the words to be under one another, to gather and not to leave the template. Font size also is reduced. I want to save my functionality, but to have h1 tag. Prefer not to install packages, if its possible.

Answer (score 0):

Col xs=12  means the div will get 100% of the width
Col xs =6 means the div will get 50% of the width

BUT

```
<Col xs={12}>
  <h1> demo </h1>
</Col>
```

and

```
<Col md={6}>
  <h1> demo </h1>
</Col>
```

Will have the **exact same h1 font-size** , yes ccols modify the width but ***not*** the font SIZE.

For this you will need **media query** (add this to your css file):

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 12px;
  }
}
```

For questions comment here

Comment: Text size comes from className="headerTitle" 
Here is a link with picture of the problem, when I write h1 tag in code. 
https://ibb.co/559XCxv
From above one is with h1 tag and its not responsive, the bottom one is without the tag and works good.

Comment: It is difficult to tell without a real example, any chance you can upload this into a jsfiddle to validate? for me it could be that col has display flex and a missing "flex-wrap: wrap" property, but who knows?